# Quickly loading small part of a NPZ file

Tags: python, numpy

I need to use a .npz file for a project, and when reading it in as such:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import numpy 
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = numpy.load('data.npz')

lst = data.files
```

no problems occur. As soon as I add something that uses it however, such as

```
subset = (data['arr_0'][1:100, :, :, :]
```

or randomly sample it (as it is very big (180 000 x 5 x 10 x 10) and I only want to use a subset), it takes forever to finish. 
Is there a way to load only the first part, or random samples, within reasonable time?

Comment: `np.load` from a `npy` file takes a `mmap_mode` parameter that allows it to read a slice of the array from the file, without loading the whole thing.  But that isn't available with `npz` files.  `npz` is a zip archive. `data` is a dictionary referencing that archive.  `data['arr_0']` extracts that file from the archive, and loads it.

Comment: Extracting the `arr_0` file from the `npz` archive first (such as with a shell zip tool), and doing a `load` with `mmap_mode` on that `arr_0.npy` might work and be faster.